# _mm_cmpistri in reverse

Tags: c++, string, sse

Let's say I have these strings:

```
char ref[30] = "1234567891234567891";
char oth[30] = "1234567891234567891";
```

I want to use the SSE 4.2 `_mm_cmpistri` function in C++; Normally the string is parsed from left to right. Is there a way to tell the function to search in reverse (compare from right to left instead of left to right?

Instead of searching 
--------------->

- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
- 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

to search this way <-----------------

Later edit:

Here's what i want to do:

I have two strings and I need a function with this header:

```
int sse_cmp(const char *a, int posA, const char *b, int posB);
```

This function must compare the strings "backwords":
from `posA` to `0` or until `posB == 0`.
The function must return the number of of common chars from back.

Ex:

```
          <--------- posA
 a : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9
 b : a b c d 7 8 9
          <---- posB
```

will return `3 ( 987 )`

What's the most efficient way to do it? ( with SSE )

Answer (score 2):

You can use _SIDD_MOST_SIGNIFICANT as part of the mode parameter to _mm_cmpistri.
See Intel SSE4 programming reference